# tar (child) error

Tags: backup, tar

I'm trying to backup my entire VM on Fedora Linux. I'm using the following command

```
tar -cvpzf / test/backup.tar.gz --exclude=/test
```

But when I do that, I come up with this error:

```
tar (child): /: Cannot open: Is a directory tar
(child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

Can somebody please explain what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 7):

You need to specify the archive name before the directory:

```
tar -cvpzf test/backup.tar.gz / --exclude=/test
```

Comment: Now I'm getting a broken pipe error...any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Name target archive file first:

```
tar -cvpzf test/backup.tar.gz ...
```

followed by the directory(ies) to tar:

```
tar -cvpzf test/backup.tar.gz / --exclude=/test
```

Answer (score -3):

needed to mkdir "your backup directory"
for the backup archive.

Comment: This does not seem to have anything to do with the question. Can you explain how this would solve the issue at hand?